# FQL not gets all my friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to get all friends of my account.
I tried following FQL. But this did not return all friends.

```
SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2 = me()
```

My Facebook account has 59 friends, but 57 friends are returned.
Other 2 friends are valid normal account. Why not returned ?

They are not my friend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The users can completely opt out of the Facebook app platform.

Your code is correct, but some of your friends have strong `privacy settings`.

This can be set by going to : 
`Privacy Settings -> Apps -> Turn off Platform`